# PHP rar file`s other way

Tags: php, rar

I have this script, it works perfect under XAMMP (windows) but when I upload it to my host will it fail because

> exec() has been disabled for security reasons

And .exe will not work on linux.

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
function RARFiles($Output='output.rar',$Files=array()) {
  $Data='';
  for($i=0;$i<count($Files);$i++) {
    $Data.="\"{$Files[$i]}\" ";
    }
    exec("rar.exe a \"{$Output}\" {$Data}");
    if(file_exists($Output)) {
        echo 'ok';
    } else {
        echo 'failed';
    }
}

$Files=array('index.php');
RARFiles('./Hier_je_files/asdf.rar',$Files);
?>
```

Is there a other way to rar files with php?

Comment: there are several compression extensions for PHP http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php see your `phpinfo()` output to check if those are installed on your host...

Comment: LMGTFY: http://php.net/manual/en/book.rar.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's own [`RarArchive`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.rararchive.php) class:

> This class represents a RAR archive, which may be formed by several
>   volumes (parts) and which contains a number of RAR entries (i.e.,
>   files, directories and other special objects such as symbolic links).